# What is the focal length of the Nexus 4 rear camera?

Tags: android, camera

The focal length of the Nexus 4 is 4.6 mm according to the Android-API-Call "getFocalLength()" and the most results of Google searches.

According to http://www.devicespecifications.com/de/model/73c42796 the focal length is 3.51 mm

According to my own calculations with the following equation, the focal length should be between 3.3 and 3.4 mm. If you consider some inaccuracy due to the height of the object in pixel, 3.51 could be a valid value.

distance (mm) = (focal length * realHeightOfObject) / (pixelHeightOfObjectInImage * physicalPixelSize)

The equation can be found in the PhD-Thesis here: http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/pastel-00802707/  (P. 121f). It works for the highest resolution of the sensor chip.

So it seems like the result of the API-Call "getFocalLength()" is incorrect for the Nexus 4 and maybe for other devices, too! That affects everything you do with this API-Call. Anybody facing the same issue, or did i miss something?

Edit:

- I did the same calculations with a Galaxy S3 that returns a focal length of 3.7 mm and this result seemed to be valid.
- Just made a little example app to check if the result of getFocalLength() changes with the focus. This is not the case. It always returns 4.6. Also in the exif-data of my images the focal length is always 4.6.

Comment: The focal length changes depending on how the camera is focused and zoomed. Do you mean minimum focal length?

Comment: Afaik the most smartphone cameras have only one fixed focal length. I think that's why there's one API-Call that returns only one focal length. Am i wrong at this point? If there is a minimum and maximum focal length, there's no api-call to get these values. 
I didn't use any zoom and i didn't focus very near objects. The distance to the objects is 2-12 meters.

Comment: I could be wrong; I think I am thinking of http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getFocusDistances(float[])

Comment: void getFocusDistances (float[] output) returns three values. Near, optimal and maximal focus distance. In my case 1.2, 2.1 and 8.0 meters. These values do not change, when the focus is changing. I don't think that this is intended behaviour, it is also reported here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515214/android-camera-focal-length-nd-focal-distances-do-not-change. The problem remains: Can we get a valid focal length for our Nexus 4?

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to get the sensor size and felt really stupid for a while now because I thought I wouldn't be able to get basic trigonometry right.

Answer (score 0):

The phone camera device has a fix focal length. The focus() changes the Image Distance (between CDD surface and convex lens). Because the input light ray from objects which you want to focus on may be not paralleled, the focus point would shift out the original fix focal length